# How would I make a dropdown list redirect to another page with specific information in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have in my `index.html.erb` page a dropdown list of the English alphabet, A->Z, with a `Select All` option. My parser takes specific words from a `.txt` and displays the words in the index page. I want to organize the page after a letter is selected with only words beginning with that letter.

I am new to Rails; with that in mind, I want to use AJAX so that the information just gets displayed on the same page.

With these in mind, I am not sure how best to progress; using JavaScript, erb, etc. As of now I currently have no code implemented and I am looking for ideas.

Comment: How far did you go, were you able to do the ajax request? or not

Comment: Hello Mohammad. I have not, as I am not sure how I would connect the arrays containing each word to each option in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

- Make the links remote: `link_to "A", index_path(letter: "A"), remote: true`
- Load the words in your index action: `@words = Word.where("word ILIKE ?", "#{params[:letter]}%")`
- And respond to JS requests: `respond_to { |format| format.js }`
- In your `index.js.erb`, render the words into the page: `$("#wordlist").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('words', words: @words)) %>");`

Comment: This answer is correct, but note that the question said dropdown list, so you'll need to trigger the ajax with `$.change` not a link

Comment: Also don't use `Word.where("word ILIKE '#{params[:letter]}%'")` it's vulnerable to sql injections, instead use `Word.where("word ILIKE ?", params[:letter])`

Comment: After I finish implementing a new change I'll get around to trying this out, and I will give feedback appropriately in a few minutes.

Comment: In which file would the `link_to` go?

Comment: Oh jesus, thanks for pointing that out Mohammad. @Altun: I was assuming you're using links in your dropdown. If you have a dropdown input, use jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.get` methods in the dropdown's `change` callback instead.